# Dynamic div content fades before it should

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that jQuery has a tooltip object, but I wanted to get a few things straight making my own for launching into using something that I didn't fully understand. I want the content to be displayed dynamically, but first I tried my hand using:

```
css: .hiddenEl{display:none;}

 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#showElement').click(function () {
            getText()
        });
        function getText() {
            $.ajax({
               //...ajax options
                success: function (data) {
                   //if I use this line of code when a div with 
                    // class hiddenEl is already on the page, it works
                    $('.hiddenEl').text(data.d).fadeToggle();
                   //when I create the div dynamically it fades in
                   //,and immediately fades back out.
                   //var $div = $('<div>').addClass('.hiddenEl').text(data.d).appendTo('body').fadeToggle();
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    console.log('failed: ' + xhr.status);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I'd like to know `why` in the version where I'm filling the div with dynamic content that it fades back out once the animation is done and in the first one it works as expected (which means the div is hidden on the second click) and how I can fix it. Secondly, I'd like to see how my version compares to someone else's who might write their own custom tooltip

EDIT: here's a non-AJAX way that's doing the same thing.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#showElement').click(function () {
                getText()
            });
            var array = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
            function getText() {
                $.ajax({
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log('success');
                        //if I use this line of code when a div with 
                        // class hiddenEl is already on the page, it works
                        // $('.hiddenEl').text(data.d).fadeToggle();
                        //when I create the div dynamically it fades in
                        //,and immediately fades back out.

                        var $div = $('<div>').addClass('.hiddenEl').text(array).appendTo('body').fadeToggle();
                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        console.log('failed: ' + xhr.status);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: It's likely because of the way you're dynamically creating the element. May we see how you do so?

Comment: @Zeaklous it's the commented line var $div = $('<div>').....

Comment: If you uncomment the var $div... line and comment out the $('.hiddenEl') line you'll see the problem.

Comment: Try using `jQuery('<div/>', {
    class: 'hiddenEl',
    text: data.d
}).appendTo('body');` Could we also see a live example if that doesn't work?

Comment: I'm fiddling around with jsFiddle to get it to use an AJAX request...